# What is the difference between TemplateRef<{ $implicit: WidgetState }>; and TemplateRef<WidgetState>; in Angular (ngTemplateOutletContext)

Tags: angular, ngtemplateoutlet

template:

```html
    <div class="widget-content">
      <ng-container
        [ngTemplateOutlet]="contentTemplate || defaultWidgetContent"
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: state }"
      ></ng-container>
      <ng-template #defaultWidgetContent>
        <div class="sky-condition">{{ state.data.skyCondition === 'sunny' ? '☀️' : '☁️' }}</div>
        <div class="temperature">{{state.data.temperature}}°C</div>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
```

component:

```
@Input() contentTemplate!: TemplateRef<{ $implicit: WidgetState }>;
```

Here, we can use

```
TemplateRef<{ $implicit: WidgetState }>
```

and

```
TemplateRef<WidgetState>
```

I know what is $implicit, but **I do not get their difference**

Both versions are equivalent and functionally the same.

**Is `TemplateRef<{ $implicit: WidgetState }>` a bit more expressive version of `TemplateRef< WidgetState>` ?**

that's all?

---

**Tutorial:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfPVdJ2oQlM

**Code:** https://github.com/DMezhenskyi/angular-template-outlet-example/commit/94d9e86055c04c5093b6bc84a8bf812dce22d9b7

Comment: [This template](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/advanced/datatables/datatables.component.html#L13-L17) is [rendered here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/datatable/src/datatable/datatable.component.html#L16). The object passed as `$implicit` ends up in the `artist` template variable (`let artist="$implicit"` or in short `let artist`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right:

1. Both versions are equivalent and functionally the same.
2. `TemplateRef<{ $implicit: WidgetState }>` is a bit more expressive version of `TemplateRef<WidgetState>`.